# Injective functions implies injective composition proof

Tags: functions

So I want to show that given sets $A$ and $B$ and the mappings:

$f: A \to B$ and $g:B\to C$

$f$ and $g$ both injective $\implies$ $g\circ f$ is injective

My attempt at a proof:

$f$ is injective $\implies \forall a_1,a_2 \in A$

$f(a_1) = f(a_2) \implies a_1 = a_2$

$g$ is injective also  so

$g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2)) \implies f(a_1) = f(a_2) \implies a_1 = a_2$

Thus $g\circ f$ is injective $\blacksquare$

Is this a valid proof?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Seems fine if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is valid.

$$g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2)) \implies f(a_1) = f(a_2) \implies a_1 = a_2$$

the first implication is due to $g$ is injective and the second implication is due to $f$ is injective.

Injective function gives us the ability to "remove" it since they must share the same pre-image.